# Word Interop - Check if a doc/x file has Superscript/Subscript text or Equations

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am building a Word File Content Analyser and I am stuck with the code, on how to check if a doc/docx file has **Superscripts/Subscripts** or **Equations** in the content.

Code I have so far is:

```
            WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            WordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
            WordApp.AutomationSecurity = MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
            WordApp.Visible = false;
            WordApp.Options.SaveInterval = 0;
            Document DocObj = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName, OpenAndRepair: false, NoEncodingDialog: true, ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: true, PasswordDocument: "dummy", PasswordTemplate: "dummy");

            PageCount = DocObj.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Pages.Count;
```

I know that I have to use `Ranges()` to select the ranges but I don't know how to do with it.

Also, the equations are those which are created using Insert/Equations panel.

Comment: you can Record Macro in Word to check the generated code http://superuser.com/questions/140374/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-equations-in-word-2007-documents, http://wordribbon.tips.net/T013110_Easily_Finding_Superscripts.html, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821988.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: if(DocObj.OMaths.Count > 0)  Equations = true;
This helped to determine the doc has equations but not the superscript/subscript. Any clue how that can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check if any part of the main document story range (doesn't include Headers, Footers and other `WdStoryType`) then something like:

```
var font = DocObj.Content.Font;
var hasSuperscripts = font.Superscript != 0;
var hasSubscripts = font.Subscript != 0;
var hasEquations = DocObj.OMaths.Count > 0;
```

Most of the Word Range properties that return `int` instead of `bool` (like .Font.Superscript and .Font.Subscript) return -1 if they are true for the whole range, 0 if they are false for the whole range, or 9999999 (wdUndefined) if they are true only for part of the range.

If you want to search the rest of the `.StoryRanges` too:

```
var hasSubscripts = DocObj.StoryRanges.Cast<Range>().Any(r => r.Font.Subscript != 0);
var hasSuperscripts = DocObj.StoryRanges.Cast<Range>().Any(r => r.Font.Superscript != 0);
```